# Crash in CFNumberCreate (malloc_zone_malloc)

Tags: ios, exception

I'm getting a number of crashes in __handleUncaughtException -> CFNumberCreate -> malloc_zone_malloc (see screenshot of crash log from Crashlytics).

Can anyone explain what might be causing this?

[image: Crash log]

Comment: Can you show us your code? related to the crash?

Comment: The crash is not associated with any of my code.  Only foundation code is show in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the crash is not caused by anything related to NSNumber or CFNumber, but is caused by messing up memory earlier, and the crash you get is just the symptom.

Google for "iOS debug memory corruption" which should give you some hints.